# UITableView in view based application

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to add a table to a view which already has a search bar and some text.

If I created a navigation based project, then I could use

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

but I can't do that inside a view based application.

I don't really need multiple section just the one. How do i do this?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you have to add a `UITableView` to your viewController, then define the delegate(s) of your tableview like:

```
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource = self;
```

This way, your table view will call your class to get its data, and to know how to present them. That means your method `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` will be called.

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly. I also added the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource protocols.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a tableView (either in code or in Interface Builder), set the delegate and datasource and then add the tableView as a subview of your current view;

So if you did it programmatically (as opposed to Interface Builder) it would look something like:

```
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource = self;
[self.view addSubView:tableView];
```

and then you need to implement the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource Protocols.

[TableView Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451)

Answer (score 0):

the method you are mentioning is part of the "UITableViewDataSource Protocol Reference" and is only remotely related to the problem you are describing. you can add a tableView (like any other view) via InterfaceBuilder or via code. In code it would look something like this:

```
UITableView* tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource = self;
[self.view addSubview:tableView];
```

(assuming that you are executing this from within a viewController).
Remember that you need to implement

```
– tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:
```

and

```
– tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

in your viewController to make this all work (see UITableViewDataSource Protocol Reference)

I suggest you take a look at "[Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)" if you haven't already!